# $cordovaCameraProvider not Supporting in Ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on an App where I need to select multiple Images from Gallery 
I used Ionic Framework to develop this App.
I have installed

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git
```

to support imagePicker .
this is my Controller

```
    .controller('ImageCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$cordovaCamera', function($scope, $rootScope, $cordovaCamera) {
  alert('fff');
}])
```

where I am just writing Alert() to check whether it's working or not.
but I am getting an error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaCameraProvider <- $cordovaCamera <- ImageCtrl
```

how do I solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:` results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.

1. Install the camera 
   `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera`
2. in your app.js, make sure you have included ngcordvoa 
   `angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])`
3. You only have to include $cordovacamera once in your function as following

   `.controller("ImageController", function ($scope, $cordovaCamera) { 
   alert('fff');
   })`

Answer (score 2):

In your `app.js` make sure you have injected `ngCordova`

```
angular.module('camera', ['ionic', 'camera.controllers', 'ngCordova'])
```